# get_footer not working boilerplate theme

Tags: theme-development, footer

I am very new to WordPress. The footer will not show up in a boilerplate theme I have. I've looked online for hours.

Here is my footer.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content
 * after.  Calls sidebar-footer.php for bottom widgets.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Boilerplate
 * @since Boilerplate 1.0
 */
?>  
        </section><!-- #main -->

        <footer role="contentinfo">

            <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
            <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Semantic Personal Publishing Platform" rel="generator">Proudly powered by WordPress </a>
        </footer><!-- footer -->
<?php
    /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
     */
    wp_footer("new");
?>


    </body>
</html>
```

here is my loop.php file (not sure if you'll need this):

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays posts.
 *
 * The loop displays the posts and the post content.  See
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to understand it and
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to understand
 * the tags used in it.
 *
 * This can be overridden in child themes with loop.php or
 * loop-template.php, where 'template' is the loop context
 * requested by a template. For example, loop-index.php would
 * be used if it exists and we ask for the loop with:
 * <code>get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );</code>
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Boilerplate
 * @since Boilerplate 1.0
 */
?>

<?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <nav id="nav-above" class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #nav-above -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php /* If there are no posts to display, such as an empty archive page */ ?>
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
    <article id="post-0" class="post error404 not-found">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'boilerplate' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'boilerplate' ); ?></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php

/* Start the Loop.
 *
 * In Twenty Ten we use the same loop in multiple contexts.
 * It is broken into three main parts: when we're displaying
 * posts that are in the gallery category, when we're displaying
 * posts in the asides category, and finally all other posts.
 *
 * Additionally, we sometimes check for whether we are on an
 * archive page, a search page, etc., allowing for small differences
 * in the loop on each template without actually duplicating
 * the rest of the loop that is shared.
 *
 * Without further ado, the loop:
 */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php /* How to display posts in the Gallery category. */ ?>

    <?php if ( in_category( _x('gallery', 'gallery category slug', 'boilerplate') ) ) : ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php boilerplate_posted_on(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

            <div class="entry-content">
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
                <?php
                    $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
                    if ( $images ) :
                        $total_images = count( $images );
                        $image = array_shift( $images );
                        $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' );
                ?>
                        <div class="gallery-thumb">
                            <a class="size-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $image_img_tag; ?></a>
                        </div><!-- .gallery-thumb -->
                        <p><em><?php printf( __( 'This gallery contains <a %1$s>%2$s photos</a>.', 'boilerplate' ),
                                'href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) . '" rel="bookmark"',
                                $total_images
                            ); ?></em></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            <footer class="entry-utility">
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( _x('gallery', 'gallery category slug', 'boilerplate'), 'category' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View posts in the Gallery category', 'boilerplate' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'More Galleries', 'boilerplate' ); ?></a>
                |
                <?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'boilerplate' ), __( '1 Comment', 'boilerplate' ), __( '% Comments', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'boilerplate' ), '|', '' ); ?>
            </footer><!-- .entry-utility -->
        </article><!-- #post-## -->

<?php /* How to display posts in the asides category */ ?>

    <?php elseif ( in_category( _x('asides', 'asides category slug', 'boilerplate') ) ) : ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>

            <footer class="entry-utility">
                <?php boilerplate_posted_on(); ?>
                |
                <?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'boilerplate' ), __( '1 Comment', 'boilerplate' ), __( '% Comments', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'boilerplate' ), '| ', '' ); ?>
            </footer><!-- .entry-utility -->
        </article><!-- #post-## -->

<?php /* How to display all other posts. */ ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="entry-info">
                <span class="entry-author">
                    <?php boilerplate_name(); ?>
                </span>
                &middot;
                <span class="posted-date">
                    <?php boilerplate_posted_on(); ?>
                </span>
            </div>

            <h3 class="entry-subtitle"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></h3>
            <div class="entry-meta">

            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

    <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>

            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php # the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php #the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
                <?php #wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'boilerplate' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

        <!--<footer class="entry-utility">
                <?php if ( count( get_the_category() ) ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Posted in %2$s', 'boilerplate' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?>
                    |
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                    $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
                    if ( $tags_list ):
                ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Tagged %2$s', 'boilerplate' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $tags_list ); ?>
                    |
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'boilerplate' ), __( '1 Comment', 'boilerplate' ), __( '% Comments', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'boilerplate' ), '| ', '' ); ?>
            </footer><!-- .entry-utility -->
        </article><!-- #post-## -->

        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

    <?php endif; // This was the if statement that broke the loop into three parts based on categories. ?>

<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>

<?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <nav id="nav-below" class="navigation">
        <?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'boilerplate' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #nav-below -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

here is my page.php file (again, not sure if you need this):

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the wordpress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your wordpress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Boilerplate
 * @since Boilerplate 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                <?php } else { ?>   
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <?php } ?>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'boilerplate' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'boilerplate' ), '', '' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                </article><!-- #post-## -->
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please format the question well esp the codes for better readability.

Comment: Is the footer not showing up on *any* page or are there specific pages where it is not working? Have you tried replacing the `wp_footer("new")` line in `footer.php` with `wp_footer()`

Comment: have you enabled DEBUG http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress and what are the error messages? what does show in the html code of your static pages in  the browser?